# How to load more jquery script to DOM by jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am creating an application that may become very large over time. So in order to keep things simple, we have decided to keep Javascript (mostly jQuery code), CSS and html for one particular feature in one file. for example, if upload is a function, then we have all the jQuery validation and css, html for upload in one file (without head and html tags).

We have a home dashboard in which a click handler will load all the links by ajax and append to the designated DIV of class indicated by additional attribute in links called "whereTOadd". so if a link has its "WhereTOadd" attribute set to ".here" and href set to upload.php then the contents of upload.php will be added to a div of class 'here' in the same page. it is done using script given below.

But the problem i am facing is that I need to include jQuery file again in every file to get the codes working, which is a terrible thing. What can be done to avoid this?

This is html of my dashboard:

```
<html>
<head>
..
<script src="Path-to-jquery-min-file.php" ></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function(){

 $(document).on("click","a",function(e){

     if( $(this).attr('href'))var ajaxurl = $(this).attr('href').valueOf();

     if( $(this).attr('whereTOadd'))
     var target = $(this).attr('whereToadd').valueOf();

      /*for ajax request */
      var options= {
            type: 'GET',
            url: ajaxurl,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (html, textStatus){
                                     $(target).empty().append(html);
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus){
                alert('error');

            }
          }
        $.ajax(options);
return false;
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="upload.php" >Upload data</a>
<div class=".here" ></div>
</body>
```

upload.php contains:

```
 <script type="javascript" >
    $('body').append('load successful!');
    </script>
```

This setup will not work until I make change in upload.php as:

```
 <script src="Path-to-jquery-min-file.php" ></script>
     <script type="javascript" >
        $('body').append('load successful!');
     </script>
```

Please help in solving this because loading jQuery again and again in the same page may cause errors and conflicts. Please suggest me a better approach to what I am doing.

Thanks

Comment: With browser caching, including the jquery in each file isn't as bad as it sounds.

Comment: @Richard : I have read somewhere that including jquery more than once disrupts the functioning, although it didnot happen in my case.

Comment: $.getScript() and $('.here').load() will help you if you can sepearte scripts from dom elements...